# Why does egit give option to commit to head?

Tags: git, github, egit

When I commit a file using egit, what is the option available to select 'head'. Also, no files are commited when I select 'head'. Should I not be commiting to master only ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearly confusing committing and pushing. The screenshot you've shown is about setting up specification used for pushes.  To understand what this dialog talks about, read the [`git-push` manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html), especially the bits dealing with the so-called "refspecs" as what that dialog supposedly is about is presenting you with a GUI interface for constructing a push refspec.